# How to export project to JAR file as lib by Gradle Builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am newbie to Gradle, i have a single project.

Now, i wanna config gradle to export for me a JAR file (as lib can be called by bash shell, no need runable jar)

My gradle build file looks like below :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

version = '1.0'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:unchecked'
    options.deprecation = true
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'XXX',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7')

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.5'

    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.2'

    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

BUT when i run my build file, it give me an error with no details.

> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Most probably you have a syntax error in your Java sources. Your build.gradle is fine.

Comment: It doesn't print *anything* before that error line?

Comment: @KDM my sources code all are OK (no compile error (by eclipse), no check style error report, no find bugs error report). Any ideas?

Comment: @Andreas : before error line is compileClasspath sub task, and it returned ok with green alert.

Comment: @TaiTran run with stacktrace and post the output. I used your build.gradle with a project and it compiletask is successful without errors.

Comment: you can get more output from gradle by appending the switches `--stacktrace`, `--info` ir even `--debug`. this should give you a hint on what is wrong.

Comment: One stacktrace report : 
XXX.java:18: エラー: この文字は、エンコーディングMS932にマップできません
 * CSV繝ｦ繝ｼ繝?繧｣繝ｪ繝?繧｣

Now, I know why.
My project was encoded at UTF-8 (Unix). But maybe gradle required encoded at MS932)

How can i force setting gradle encoded at UTF-8 (Unix). It's my requirement, i can not change it!

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

For anyone have a same issue.

I add configuration Gradle compiler encoding as below and it worked.

```
eclipseJdt << {
    ant.propertyfile(file: ".settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs") {
        ant.entry(key: "eclipse.preferences.version", value: "1")
        ant.entry(key: "encoding/<project>", value: "utf-8")
    }
}

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
```